# Separate sub-strings by adding spaces

Tags: string, vbscript

I have a text file (.txt) and I need to add many spaces into a row.
My input strings have 4 dates in one contiguous string (not divided). For example:

> ```
> 20150612201506122015061220150612
> ```

It must be divided every 8 characters by adding a space: `yyyyMMdd yyyyMMdd yyyyMMdd yyyyMMdd`

> ```
> 20150612 20150612 20150612 20150612
> ```

I have tried with `left` and `right` functions, but I don't know how to use them to cut 8 characters and insert a space `" "`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a quick `For` loop:

```
strIn = "20150612201506122015061220150612"

'add a space every 8 characters
For intChar = 1 To Len(strIn) Step 8
    strOut = strOut & Mid(strIn, intChar, 8) & " "
Next

'remove last space
strOut = Left(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
```

From your comment, here is another method to split the string, if the string has variable length strings inside of it:

```
strIn = "020031000420150612201506122015061220150612"
'to transform in 02 003 1 0004 20150612 20150612 20150612 20150612"

intStart = 1
For Each charCount In Array(2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8)
    strOut = strOut & Mid(strIn, intStart, charCount) & " "
    intStart = intStart + charCount
Next


'remove last space
intStr = Left(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
```

Here we use `For each charCount in Array()` and the list of fields lengths is in the array.

Comment: and if the row not have the same space to divide ? for example 2 space, 3 space, 1 space, 4 space etc ?

Comment: Then how would you know, as a human, where to separate the string?

Comment: i can receive receive a file with different row with first 2char,3char 1 char 4 char and the date of past example.  Example 020031000420150612201506122015061220150612 to transform in 02 003 1 0004 20150612 20150612 20150612 20150612

Comment: I've updated the answer with an optional approach for variable length, fixed width strings.